Yet another .htaccess RewriteRule Condition not being met
This is the baseurl "http://tkrn.io/u/tkrn/1337test.exe" and I'm looking to rewrite it to "http://files.tkrn.io/tkrn/1337test.exe"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u\/(.*)$ http://files.tkrn.io/$1 [R=301,L]

This unit test passed htaccess tester but when running it on the server it does not redirect correctly. It redirects to "http://files.tkrn.io/u/tkrn/1337test.exe" which is not correct.
Here is the unit test: https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=49fc04cf-2c16-4da1-9943-3f3e1e7ae544
Help!

You probably have more rewrite configuration than just this, I'm guessing - so show us the full thing, please, so that we can see what else might perhaps interfere.

This is .htaccess in the root /. No folders no .htaccess in /u/
`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ http://files.tkrn.io/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]`

Please do not add additional information into comments. It is nearly impossible to read such code. There is an "edit" link below your question, use it to update your question to include and mark the additional information. Thanks!

Since the "wrong" result of the redirection is identical to the originally requested path I assume that redirection is not performed by a (or your) redirection rule, but by something generic on host level. Maybe your setup offers something like a generic redirection between hosts or similar.
